# Слово "самоё" - "самоё мысль оставляю как есть"

Tags: лексика, устаревшие-слова, лексическая-сочетаемость, грамотная-речь

*Самоё мысль оставляю как есть — как Вам бог на душу положил...*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вполне, если Вы хотели создать стилизацию книжной письменной речи. Это вин. пад. мест. ж.рода:**саму** е**ё** мысль = самоё.

Answer (score 3):

Местоимение использовано верно. Только эта книжная форма винительного падежа.